# need help with finding mass and height of the ball?

Tags: physics

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIRkO.png

I have : h =1.7m , M = 0.65 kg, v i = sqrt 2gh = 5.77

vf = 2m / M + m (-vi) + m-M / m+M (vi) = 0.

But this cannot be reduced because there are too many m's. How then can it be solved?

Comment: You should try asking physics questions on physics stack exchange

Comment: They don't allow questions. Can you help?

Comment: @user435428 You mean the Q&A physics stack exchange site doesn't allow questions?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/ 

This link

Comment: Tried it before. Mods told me they don't accept questions. I'll try it later, maybe they changed the rules.

Comment: @KSplitX Physics.SE has a different policy on homework questions than math.SE.  They don't usually accept them.  So there's no point in sending questioners there.  You can either answer physics hw questions here or vote to close as off topic (assuming you have enough rep).

Comment: @user435428 stack exchange allows questions - just not homework questions.  You can ask any question you want but it has to be about content, you can't ask for the sake of the answer for a grade in school.  Try rephrasing the question to make it not a request for a homework answer but confirmation of the content on the physics curriculum you're learning.  You will have a much more positive response if you ask a content-based, not homework-based, question.

Comment: @user435428 This is an elastic collision problem.  That means you'll have two equations: conservation of momentum and conservation of kinetic energy.

Comment: BTW, to learn MathJax, see [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  For starters, to write $$v_f = \frac{2m}{M} + m (-v_i) + \frac{m-M}{m+M} (vi) = 0$$ you'd type `$$v_f = \frac{2m}{M} + m (-v_i) + \frac{m-M}{m+M} (vi) = 0$$` (not sure if that's what you were going for, but you should be able to see how to modify it).  While it might be hard to get answers to physics questions here anyway (this is a math site afterall), it certainly wouldn't hurt your chances if you wrote it up so it was easier to read.